# Representing js.Dynamic in an object or class

Tags: scala.js

Say I want to produce the following javascript:

```
var myObj = { x: 'a', y: 'b' }
```

I can do this by callaing js.Dynamic.literal:

```
val myObj = js.Dynamic.literal(x = "a", y = "b")
```

But I can also represent this kind of info in a class:

```
@js.native
object MyObj extends js.Object {
    val x = "a"
    val y = "b"
}

val myObj = MyObj
```

But since I upgraded to 6.21 this causes the compiler warnings:

> Members of traits, classes and objects extending js.Any may only
>   contain members that call js.native. This will be enforced in 1.0.
>
> val x = "a"
>
> ...

Is there I way I can continue with this approach going forward?

Comment: I think this should work the same way just without the `@js.native` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redo it on [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7RxG2gU/0).

The exception looks a bit different, but doing as suggested the final solution without warnings looks like this:

```
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.ScalaJSDefined

@ScalaJSDefined
object MyObj extends js.Object {
    val x = "a"
    val y = "b"
}

println(MyObj.x + MyObj.y)
```

Here the [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7RxG2gU/1).